# API gateway and microservices communication

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, graphql, microservices, apollo-client

I am building microservices arhitecture and i need help with communication. What is best approach for API gateway to communicate with services ? My API gateway will be `graphql apollo` server and services will be `REST APIs.` Should i use REST to communicate with services or some message system like `RabbitMQ ?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it both ways but using a message broker system like **RabbitMQ will give you the advantage of load balancing**. With HTTP rest communication, you need a load balancer so that traffic is distributed and routed to the various instances. But with a message broker like RabbitMQ, **broker itself is the load balancer**. If multiple consumers are listening same address at the same time messages will be delivered parallel instead of blocking each other as the behavior of HTTP. I hope I could explain it clearly :)

You can look at this [article](https://solace.com/blog/experience-awesomeness-event-driven-microservices) which explains the advantages.

Comment: One more question for you @onuriltan. Can i use maybe gRpc to communicate between gateway and services, for example authentication service and gateway and use message broker for communication between services ? Or should I use message broker always ?

Comment: @Lule yes you can also use gRPC, it is also faster, but I found that it is harder to use because you need to implement broadcasting, pub-sub, security among different points etc. RabbitMQ I find is more easy to configure and implement.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Going with RabbitMQ then.