# api gateway and kong + rabbitmq on nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, api-gateway, kong

Hello I'm starting to study microservices, api gateway and others

and I have the following doubts
I have 2 microservices

service a and service b

and then I want to have a gateway api to communicate with these services by messaging with rabbitmq,
i found a gateway api: kong seems to be very interesting, but i couldn't imagine if it is possible to do this that describe with kong

an api manager to send messages to the end point through rabbitmq

Comment: I think you are looking for service discovery and invocation mechanisms for your microservices. this article might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126710/api-gateway-and-microservices-communication .
I found somethings on similar lines : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126710/api-gateway-and-microservices-communication
Well, I think both reads will give you an idea to support your use case.

Comment: @bron10 that's really it, but i'm a little confused how can i implement in nodejs with kong and rabbitmq